# android graph-view y axis numbers being cut out

Tags: java, android-studio, android-graphview

When trying to create a line graph with the graph-view library in android studio part of the numbers on the vertical line are being cut out.Does anybody know how to fix this?

```
<com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dip"
            android:id="@+id/graph"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

final GraphView graph = (GraphView)findViewById(R.id.graph);
final LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> graphSeries = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[] { 
    }); // the points are added progressively`
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. The fix I currently found is to set the padding in the GridLabelRenderer associated with the graph with:

```
GraphView gv = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
GridLabelRenderer glr = gv.getGridLabelRenderer();
glr.setPadding(32); // should allow for 3 digits to fit on screen
```

As I understand it, the graphview graph expects to have the full screen width by default, so it is cut off by the default padding for the android app (16dp). Setting this padding value in the GridLabelRenderer adds more padding to the graph's edges, decreasing your graph's actual graphing area but allowing more room for the numbers.

For reference, the default padding value associated with the GridLabelRenderer is 20.

I imagine there is a more elegant solution, but this is all I was able to come up with. Hope this helps anybody who comes up with the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

you can set width of label with following method

```
mGraph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelVerticalWidth(int width)
```

Maybe you want set value according to the number of digits

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

maybe it should be

```
android:layout_height="200dp"
```

instead. Best yet, you can specify

```
graph.getViewport().setMinY(0.0);
graph.getViewport().setMaxY(100.0);
```

Just my 2 cents :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I also ended up setting the padding larger. It worked for me but there must be away to have it adjust relative to the labels.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but for developers with the same problem you can use:

`graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHumanRounding(true);`

NOTE: If you are using dates as your x-axis you want to set this to false so that the formatting looks nice. However, if your x-axis is not dates, and you want to round all the axes values then this will work.