# Android GraphView - How to use separate LabelFormatter?

Tags: android, android-graphview

I'm using [Android GraphView](http://www.android-graphview.org/). I want to use `DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter` for **x-axis**, and a custom `LabelFormatter` for **y-axis**. Otherwise the y-axis labels gets cut off. See this: [android graph-view y axis numbers being cut out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36231032/android-graph-view-y-axis-numbers-being-cut-out)

If I use static padding as suggested in the answers of above question, then there is extra padding sometimes.

See the images below:

1. When there are integers in y-labels (and I have given large padding to cope with numbers like: -0.0231, -0.0450, etc.):
   [image]
2. When there are floating points in y-labels (and I have give small padding to make it look nice for numbers like: 10, 25, 40, etc): 
   [image]

And I'm unable to find the sweet spot.

If I could use a separate for both of the axes then I would set `setMaximumFractionDigits(2)`, and provide a static padding. That remove my problem. But I couldn't do both, it seem to override the other (see the code for better understanding). I can either use `DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter` or a `DefaultLabelFormatter` but not both at the same time.

Here is the code:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
nf.setMaximumIntegerDigits(2);
graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter(MainActivity.this, simpleDateFormat));
graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DefaultLabelFormatter(nf, nf)); // This overrides the previous LabelFormatter

// If I try to set them both together. I get this error.
graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter(MainActivity.this, simpleDateFormat), nf);
//setLabelFormatter (LabelFormatter) in GridLabelRenderer cannot be applied to (DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter, java.text.NumberFormat)
```

How do I use both of the `LabelFormatter` separately for both axes?